# Bug in Minimax Algorithm for Tic Tac Toe

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I am currently trying to teach myself the Minimax algorithm and I have tried to implement it in java in tic tac toe. There is a bug in my algorithm however and I can't figure out what's causing it.

Below is the complete source code (Sorry for wall of text!):

```
public class TicTacToe {
    private static boolean gameEnded = false;
    private static boolean player = true;
    private static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static Board board = new Board();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(board);
        while(!gameEnded){
            Position position = null;
            if(player){
                position = makeMove();
                board = new Board(board, position, PlayerSign.Cross);
            }else{
                board = findBestMove(board);
            }               
            player = !player;
                System.out.println(board);
                evaluateGame();
        }
    }

    private static Board findBestMove(Board board) {
        ArrayList<Position> positions = board.getFreePositions();
        Board bestChild = null;
        int previous = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for(Position p : positions){
            Board child = new Board(board, p, PlayerSign.Circle);
            int current = max(child);
            System.out.println("Child Score: " + current);
            if(current > previous){
                bestChild = child;
                previous = current;
            }
        }
        return bestChild;
    }

    public static int max(Board board){
        GameState gameState = board.getGameState();
        if(gameState == GameState.CircleWin)
            return 1;
        else if(gameState == GameState.CrossWin)
            return -1;
        else if(gameState == GameState.Draw)
            return 0;
        ArrayList<Position> positions = board.getFreePositions();
        int best = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for(Position p : positions){
            Board b = new Board(board, p, PlayerSign.Cross);
            int move = min(b);
            if(move > best)
                best = move;
        }       
        return best;
    }

    public static int min(Board board){
        GameState gameState = board.getGameState();
        if(gameState == GameState.CircleWin)
            return 1;
        else if(gameState == GameState.CrossWin)
            return -1;
        else if(gameState == GameState.Draw)
            return 0;
        ArrayList<Position> positions = board.getFreePositions();
        int best = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for(Position p : positions){
            Board b = new Board(board, p, PlayerSign.Circle);
            int move = max(b);
            if(move < best)
                best = move;
        }
        return best;
    }

    public static void evaluateGame(){
        GameState gameState = board.getGameState();
        gameEnded = true;
        switch(gameState){
            case CrossWin : 
                System.out.println("Game Over! Cross Won!");
                break;
            case CircleWin : 
                System.out.println("Game Over! Circle Won!");
                break;
            case Draw : 
                System.out.println("Game Over! Game Drawn!");
                break;
            default : gameEnded = false;
                break;
        }
    }

    public static Position makeMove(){
        Position position = null;
        while(true){
            System.out.print("Select column(x-axis). 0, 1 or 2: ");
            int column = getColOrRow();
            System.out.print("Select row(y-axis). 0, 1 or 2: ");
            int row = getColOrRow();
            position = new Position(column, row);
            if(board.isMarked(position))
                System.out.println("Position already marked!");
            else break;
        }
        return position;
    }

    private static int getColOrRow(){
        int ret = -1;
        while(true){
            try{
                ret = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e){}
            if(ret < 0 | ret > 2)
                System.out.print("\nIllegal input... please re-enter: ");
            else break;
        }
        return ret;
    }
}

public enum PlayerSign{
    Cross, Circle
}

public enum GameState {
    Incomplete, CrossWin, CircleWin, Draw
}

public final class Position {
    public final int column;
    public final int row;

    public Position(int column, int row){
        this.column = column;
        this.row = row;
    }
}

public class Board {
    private char[][] board; //e = empty, x = cross, o = circle.

    public Board(){
        board = new char[3][3];
        for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
            for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
                board[x][y] = 'e'; //Board initially empty
    }

    public Board(Board from, Position position, PlayerSign sign){
        board = new char[3][3];
        for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
            for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
                board[x][y] = from.board[x][y];
        board[position.column][position.row] = sign==PlayerSign.Cross ? 'x':'o';
    }

    public ArrayList<Position> getFreePositions(){
        ArrayList<Position> retArr = new ArrayList<Position>();     
        for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
            for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
                if(board[x][y] == 'e')
                    retArr.add(new Position(x, y));
        return retArr;
    }

    public GameState getGameState(){    
        if(hasWon('x'))
            return GameState.CrossWin;
        else if(hasWon('o'))
            return GameState.CircleWin;
        else if(getFreePositions().size() == 0)
            return GameState.Draw;
        else return GameState.Incomplete;
    }

    private boolean hasWon(char sign){ //8 ways to win.
        if(board[1][1] == sign){ 
            if(board[0][0] == sign && board[2][2] == sign)
                return true;
            if(board[0][2] == sign && board[2][0] == sign)
                return true;
            if(board[1][0] == sign && board[1][2] == sign)
                return true;
            if(board[0][1] == sign && board[2][1] == sign)
                return true;
            }
            if(board[0][0] == sign){
                if(board[0][1] == sign && board[0][2] == sign)
                    return true;
                if(board[1][0] == sign && board[2][0] == sign)
                    return true;
            }
            if(board[2][2] == sign){
                if(board[1][2] == sign && board[0][2] == sign)
                    return true;
                if( board[2][1] == sign && board[2][0] == sign)
                    return true;
            }   
            return false;
    }

    public boolean isMarked(Position position){
        if(board[position.column][position.row] != 'e')
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String retString = "\n";
        for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++){
            for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++){
                if(board[x][y] ==  'x' || board[x][y] == 'o')
                    retString += "["+board[x][y]+"]";
                else
                    retString += "[ ]";
            }
            retString += "\n";
        }       
        return retString;
    }   
}
```

Here is the output when I run the program (Computer is circle):

```
[ ][ ][ ]  
[ ][ ][ ]  
[ ][ ][ ]  
Select column(x-axis). 0, 1 or 2: 1  
Select row(y-axis). 0, 1 or 2: 1  
[ ][ ][ ]  
[ ][x][ ]  
[ ][ ][ ]  
Child Score: 0  
Child Score: 0  
Child Score: 0  
Child Score: 0  
Child Score: 0  
Child Score: 0  
Child Score: 0  
Child Score: 0  
[o][ ][ ]  
[ ][x][ ]  
[ ][ ][ ]  
Select column(x-axis). 0, 1 or 2: 0  
Select row(y-axis). 0, 1 or 2: 1  
[o][ ][ ]  
[x][x][ ]  
[ ][ ][ ]  
Child Score: -1  
Child Score: 0  
Child Score: 0  
Child Score: -1  
Child Score: -1  
Child Score: -1  
[o][ ][o]  
[x][x][ ]  
[ ][ ][ ]  
Select column(x-axis). 0, 1 or 2:
```

As you can see after the first move, the computer thinks that no matter what move it makes it can get a draw (Score = 0).

On the second move I put a cross on column 0, row 1. For some reason, the computer then thinks that there are two possible moves to reach a draw (Score = 0) and only four moves to lose (Score = -1). It then makes an incorrect move thinking it will get a draw.

I first thought that there was something wrong with the hasWon method, but I have tested all 8 ways of getting three in a row and they all return true.

I suspect that the problem exists somewhere in the findBestMove, max or min methods, but I haven't been able to figure out exactly what is causing it.

I would really appreciate it if someone could tell what is causing the bug or give any suggestions on how to better debug my recursive algorithm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks to me like you mixed up parts of `min` and `max`. Currently, your `max` returns the value of the worst possible move (for him) the *human* could take, instead of the optimal move the computer could take. Likewise, min returns the value of the worst move the *computer* could take, instead of the optimal move for the opponent.

Fix this by switching the PlayerSigns in `min` and `max`, and `findBestMove` should call `min`, not `max`.